# Analysis Services 2008 configuration for OWC 10

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-office, ssas

We're upgrading a data warehouse from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 R2. A favorite user reporting tool is a web site using OWC 10 (Office Web Components) -- it's basically ASPX pages connected to the Analysis Services 2000 database via the OWC object.

We migrated the warehouse SQL tables and Analysis Services database into 2008. I'm trying to get the OWC10 web site to connect to the 2008 R2 Analysis Services. I changed the ASPX connection definitions to the new server, and can see them in debug messages. However the web page gives me the error "Cannot connect to the server 'blahblah.blah.com' The server is either not started or too busy."

I suspect there are permissions or security setups required to open up Analysis Services 2008 for OWC10 queries. Has anyone done this or similar? Any ideas where to look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the provider in the connection string to MSOLAP.4 instead of the default MSOLAP.2